# Insert values into array

Tags: php, arrays

Multi-dimensional array: each record has a title and array with day of the week as a key and a value. I'm trying to insert those values into according day of the week (based on key) of existing array.
The code:

```
foreach($records as $rec)
        {

             $row = array(
                            'title' => $rec['title'], 
                            'Monday' => '', 
                            'Tuesday'=> '',
                            'Wednesday'=> '',
                            'Thursday' =>'', 
                            'Friday'   => '');


            foreach($rec['dates'] as $dtow)
            {
                $dow = explode(' ', $dtow)[0];
                $value = explode(' ', $dtow)[1];

                if($dow....blah blah that's where I'm getting lost...

            }
             $data[] = $row;
        }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDITED:
Sorry, that's probably better...

```
 Event ||     Monday ||   Tuesday ||    Wednesday ||    Thursday || Friday
 Bthd  ||   12:00    ||           ||     14:30    ||             ||
 Prty  ||            ||   18:45   ||     17:30    ||             || 14:15       
 Wdng  ||   9:00     ||           ||              ||   13:30     ||
```

Comment: Put the `$data[] = $row` part inside the second foreach, right now it's outside so you add only the last row.

Comment: Thanks Ende, but by using echo $this->table->generate($data); I see that it works just as I need..

Comment: Could you show expected input => output? Even a bad explanation can make sense if people can see the end results.

Comment: Also having trouble trying to understand what exactly you want. The expected result would be very usefull.

Comment: AAA!! I got it working... Sorry guys... That's the line I was after: $row[$dow] = $value;  Boy that was easy!!!!! Thaks anyways!!!